При попытке собрать билд с включённым плагином Unreal.js в UE 5.1.1 выдаётся ошибка
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: begin: stack for UAT
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: === Critical error: ===
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: Fatal error!
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address `0`x0000000000000040
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffe267629e5 UnrealEditor-JavascriptConsole.dll!FJavascriptCommandExecutor::CacheJavascriptContext() [D:\build\U5M-Marketplace\Sync\LocalBuilds\PluginTemp\HostProject\Plugins\UnrealJS\Source\JavascriptConsole\Private\JavascriptCommandExecutor.cpp:115]
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffe2676193f UnrealEditor-JavascriptConsole.dll!FJavascriptCommandExecutor::FJavascriptCommandExecutor() [D:\build\U5M-Marketplace\Sync\LocalBuilds\PluginTemp\HostProject\Plugins\UnrealJS\Source\JavascriptConsole\Private\JavascriptCommandExecutor.cpp:15]
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffe267618c0 UnrealEditor-JavascriptConsole.dll!SharedPointerInternals::NewIntrusiveReferenceController<1,FJavascriptCommandExecutor>() [D:\RocketSync\5.1.0-23058290+++UE5+Release-5.1\Working\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Templates\SharedPointerInternals.h:445]
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffe2676445a UnrealEditor-JavascriptConsole.dll!FJavascriptConsoleModule::StartupModule() [D:\build\U5M-Marketplace\Sync\LocalBuilds\PluginTemp\HostProject\Plugins\UnrealJS\Source\JavascriptConsole\Private\JavascriptConsoleModule.cpp:15]
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffe76ace23e UnrealEditor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffeea1cd434 UnrealEditor-Projects.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffeea1e33e4 UnrealEditor-Projects.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffeea1cd17f UnrealEditor-Projects.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff787ddac15 UnrealEditor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff787dd2688 UnrealEditor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff787dd296a UnrealEditor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff787dd5680 UnrealEditor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff787de71b4 UnrealEditor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff787de96f2 UnrealEditor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007fff04a2257d KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007fff058aaa48 ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): LogWindows: Error: end: stack for UAT
PackagingResults: Error: begin: stack for UAT
PackagingResults: Error: === Critical error: ===
PackagingResults: Error: Fatal error!
PackagingResults: Error: Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x0000000000000040
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffe267629e5 UnrealEditor-JavascriptConsole.dll!FJavascriptCommandExecutor::CacheJavascriptContext() [D:\build\U5M-Marketplace\Sync\LocalBuilds\PluginTemp\HostProject\Plugins\UnrealJS\Source\JavascriptConsole\Private\JavascriptCommandExecutor.cpp:115]
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffe2676193f UnrealEditor-JavascriptConsole.dll!FJavascriptCommandExecutor::FJavascriptCommandExecutor() [D:\build\U5M-Marketplace\Sync\LocalBuilds\PluginTemp\HostProject\Plugins\UnrealJS\Source\JavascriptConsole\Private\JavascriptCommandExecutor.cpp:15]
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffe267618c0 UnrealEditor-JavascriptConsole.dll!SharedPointerInternals::NewIntrusiveReferenceController<1,FJavascriptCommandExecutor>() [D:\RocketSync\5.1.0-23058290+++UE5+Release-5.1\Working\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Templates\SharedPointerInternals.h:445]
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffe2676445a UnrealEditor-JavascriptConsole.dll!FJavascriptConsoleModule::StartupModule() [D:\build\U5M-Marketplace\Sync\LocalBuilds\PluginTemp\HostProject\Plugins\UnrealJS\Source\JavascriptConsole\Private\JavascriptConsoleModule.cpp:15]
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffe76ace23e UnrealEditor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffeea1cd434 UnrealEditor-Projects.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffeea1e33e4 UnrealEditor-Projects.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffeea1cd17f UnrealEditor-Projects.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff787ddac15 UnrealEditor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff787dd2688 UnrealEditor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff787dd296a UnrealEditor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff787dd5680 UnrealEditor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff787de71b4 UnrealEditor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff787de96f2 UnrealEditor-Cmd.exe!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007fff04a2257d KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007fff058aaa48 ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: end: stack for UAT
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): Took 23,0418599s to run UnrealEditor-Cmd.exe, ExitCode=3
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): ERROR: Cook failed.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows):        (see C:\Users\darek\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\D+Program+Files+UE5+UE_5.1\Log.txt for full exception trace)
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): AutomationTool executed for 0h 1m 30s
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=25 (Error_UnknownCookFailure)
PackagingResults: Error: Cook failed.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): BUILD FAILED
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Cook Failure
LogAudioMixer: Warning: Decoder Error, stopping source [CompileFailed]
LogDerivedDataCache: C:/Users/darek/AppData/Local/UnrealEngine/Common/DerivedDataCache: Maintenance finished in +00:00:05.277 and deleted 0 files with total size 0 MiB. Scanned 3506 files in 3475 folders with total size 109 MiB.
LogUObjectHash: Compacting FUObjectHashTables data took   0.43ms
LogLiveCoding: Display: Starting LiveCoding
LogLiveCoding: Display: LiveCodingConsole Arguments: UnrealEditor Win64 Development
LogLiveCoding: Display: First instance in process group "UE_Person_0xe93081f9", spawning console
LogLiveCoding: Display: Waiting for server
LogLiveCoding: Display: Successfully initialized, removing startup thread

2 дня пытаюсь решить. Пробовал менять версию UE на 5.0.3, менял версии SDK, молился богам, но всё тщетно. В сети только пара вопросов по этой ошибке, но и те без ответов.
